# Assign multiple variables that reference each other, using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'd like to assign a value to a variable, then use that variable to create a new variable. The syntax for `data.table` supports multiple assignment, but apparently not with internal references. The "i" and "by" clauses in my real use-case are more complicated, so I'd prefer not to have repeating code like this:

```
require(data.table)

dt <- data.table(
  x = 1:5, 
  y = 2:6
)

# this works
dt[x == 3, z1 := x + y]
dt[x == 3, z2 := z1 + 5]

# but I wish this worked
dt[x == 3, `:=`(
  z1 = x + y,
  z2 = z1 + 5
)]
```

In contrast, this works in dplyr:

```
require(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:5, 
  y = 2:6
)

df <- mutate(df,
  z1 = x + y,
  z2 = z1 + 5
)
```

Is there a clean way to do this using data.table?

EDIT: 
Tweaking akrun's solution slightly, I figured out a way to keep the readable, sequential syntax I was looking for. It's just doing all of the operations outside the list:

```
dt[x==3, c('z1','z2','z3') := {
  z1 <- x+y
  z2 <- z1 + 5
  z3 <- z2 + 6
  list(z1, z2, z3) 
}]
```

Comment: The option you showed for `dplyr` is not the same as in `data.table` as it is not filtering for `x==3`  In `dplyr`, I am guessing either we need `ifelse` or do a `filter`, do the `mutate` and `left_join` which should be expensive if I am not wrong.

Comment: That's true. I just brought it up as an example of internal reference. I think I'll leave it as-is because I already know dplyr is slower. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use curly brackets to create the temporary variables, then place them in a `list` along with the calculation based on that variable, assign (`:=`) to the columns we need to create.

```
dt[x==3, c('z1', 'z2') := {
             z1 <- x+y
             list(z1, z1+5) 
             }]
dt
#   x y z1 z2
#1: 1 2 NA NA
#2: 2 3 NA NA
#3: 3 4  7 12
#4: 4 5 NA NA
#5: 5 6 NA NA
```

To make it a bit more faster, we can use `setkey`

```
setkey(dt, x)[(3),  c('z1', 'z2') := {
                                   z1 <- x+y
                              list(z1, z1+5)
                  }]
```

#### Benchmarks

```
set.seed(24)
dt1 <- data.table(x = sample(1:9, 1e8, replace=TRUE), y = sample(5:9, 1e8, replace=TRUE))

dt2 <- copy(dt1)
dt3 <- copy(dt1)

akrun1 <- function(){dt1[x==3, c('z1', 'z2') := {
             z1 <- x+y
                 list(z1, z1+5) 
             }]
   }

akrun2 <- function() {setkey(dt3, x)[(3),  c('z1', 'z2') := {
                                   z1 <- x+y
                              list(z1, z1+5)
                  }]
}


rsoren  <- function() {
    dt2[x == 3, z1 := x + y]
    dt2[x == 3, z2 := z1 + 5]
        }



library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(akrun1(), akrun2(), rsoren(), unit= "relative", times = 20L)
#Unit: relative
#     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
# akrun1() 1.597267 1.605404 1.393016 1.642584 1.538929 0.8634406    20
# akrun2() 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.0000000    20
# rsoren() 2.584153 2.586185 2.179601 2.694469 2.468219 0.9740701    20
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the ```z1 <- x+y``` part is base R and doesn't take advantage of assignment in place with ```:=```. I'm really looking for speed (hence the reluctant switch from dplyr) but you're right that this technically works. Already an improvement over what I had

Comment: @rsoren Here the assignment happens  only once (`:=`) if you have checked the code and also you don't have to do the `x==3` multiple times which will again slow down the code.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean with one assignment. What do you mean checked the code?

Comment: @rsoren I meant if you have looked the code carefully

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to keep this open for a while in hopes that someone can avoid the ```c('var1','var2','var3') := {stuff1;stuff2;stuff3}``` syntax, which I don't find as readable as something like my dplyr example

Comment: @rsoren If I quote yours `I'd prefer not to have repeating code like this:`.  So, it is not clear whether you are looking for efficiency or repeating the code?

Comment: I assume that all data.table solutions to this would have roughly the same speed. Among those, I prefer to have the most readable option because I'm collaborating with people who don't use R so much. If there really is a conflict though, I'd choose efficiency

Comment: @rsoren Both my methods seems to be faster than yours and it also avoids the repeated syntax.  Updated with the benchmarks.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Last question: if I've already set the key on other variables, would there be potential speed losses by setting it back and forth multiple times? -- this will be happening in a loop. I think it sorts the data on the key, which takes time

Comment: @rsoren For the first time it runs it takes time, but in subsequent runs it will be faster as it is already keyed